# A local variable is changing when being passed into a new subroutine- but no value is being returned

Tags: python, function

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
def Menu():
    ##Menu actions
    old=stock_list[:]
    print(old+" before")
    Save(stock_list[:])
    print(old+" after")

def Save(list_of_stock):
    ##change each element of the list to be a code object
```

This is the output I get:

```
[["DVI cable"], [], [], []] before
[[<code object <module> at 0x037630F0, file "<string>", line 1>], [], [], []]
```

As you can see, even though in the 'Menu' function, old shouldn't change, but it does

Comment: You're only making a *shallow* copy of the list, meaning the outermost `[]` is being copied, but each list object within that list isn't.

Comment: If `old` really is a list, `print(old+" before")` will throw error.

Comment: For compound objects you may have to use deepcopy instead of shallow copy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when you pass `old` as an argument to `Save` a shallow copy of `old` is passed into `Save`. When you do some changes in `Save` it got reflected in `old` as well. using `deepcopy` to pass that list will prevent that from happening.

```
from copy import deepcopy


def Menu():
    ##Menu actions
    old = stock_list[:]
    print(f"{old} before")
    Save(deepcopy(old))
    print(f"{old} after")
```

---

`copy.copy(x)` Return a shallow copy of x.

`copy.deepcopy(x)` Return a deep copy of x.

The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances)

- A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the
  extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
  the original.
- A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively,
  inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#module-copy